# "Missing request header "exception in Spring boot controller on production not on local server

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am getting below error on Production env but application working on local system.

```
"timestamp":"2019-04-02T10:10:26.362+0000","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Missing request header " on......
```

I am passing below Request header from browser:

```
LIB_AUTH_TOKEN: admin@gmail.com:admin



 @RestController
    public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
    public String hello(@RequestHeader(value="LIB_AUTH_TOKEN") String token){

    System.out.println(token);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Include HttpServletResponse in your Request. This would set the header at run time.
eg:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login")
    public String hello(@RequestHeader(value="LIB_AUTH_TOKEN") String token, HttpServletResponse aResponse)
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply,i Would like to add one more note,this is working fine on developer machine but its not working when we deploy same code on production env.

Answer (score 0):

Executing:

```
curl -i -H "LIB_AUTH_TOKEN: test123" -X GET http://localhost:8080/login
```

Here is working fine with POST and GET, just add a response:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/login")
    public String hello(@RequestHeader(value="LIB_AUTH_TOKEN") String token){

        System.out.println(token);

        return "hi";
    }
}
```

**Update**

Specifying the HTTP method:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String hello(@RequestHeader(value="LIB_AUTH_TOKEN") String token){

        System.out.println(token);

        return "hi";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable reply,i Would like to add one more note,this is working fine on developer machine but its not working when we deploy same code on production env.

Comment: So probably is the OPTIONS request sent by the browser before the POST, in the way the method is written there is a hello for the OPTIONS too, so your browser is not sending the header.
One solution is to specify the HTTP method for hello.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue, but in my case I wanted it to be optional. The thing is that **require** attribute for @RequestHeader is **true** by default (and I was assuming it was false by default)

Hopefully this will save someone's time!